# Adding tabs inside custom app in Microsoft teams

Tags: tabs, microsoft-teams

I have added custom app in Microsoft teams. Currently, there are three tabs viz., chat, files and about. I need to add one more tab inside my custom made app, which is a HTML page. How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's important to know that there are two "types" of tabs in Teams - the first is one that gets installed into an App the user installs to their own account directly, which it sounds like you've got with a bot right now. The user would go to the app store directly in Teams to do this. This is called a "personal" or "static" tab.

The second type of tab is one you install into a Team's channel, or a group chat, and is therefore basically 'shared' with other users. For instance, inside an existing channel, you could add a Tab for Planner. This is a 'shared' tab, and requires a separate page to be shown first when the user installs the tab for the first time, allowing them to customize the tab for the specific scenario. If you add a 'SharePoint' tab to a channel, for example, there is a small window that pops up asking you *which* SharePoint item you're trying to add. This 'Configuration' screen is a required part of building these kinds of tabs.

In the end, both kinds of tabs are basically just embedded/iframed web pages though, so if you are fimiliar with any web technology you can build these (asp.net, php, node, etc.). You do need to create an application 'definition' file (called a manifest) to tell Teams where you tab is hosted, and some other details. You might have done this already for your custom app, perhaps using App Studio. If so, you would just be adding a new section to this manifest for your tab.